# Virtual & Template method C++

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I have the same implementation for 2 methods, they both insert argument to a text file.

```
void WriteToFile( double content) //for double
{
    streamFile << content;
    streamFile << flush;
}

void WriteToFile( int content) //for integer
{
    streamFile << content;
    streamFile << flush;
}
```

The implementation is same, therefore I merge them to a template method:

```
template < class T>
void WriteToFile(T content)
{
    streamFile << content;
    streamFile << flush;
}
```

But the `WriteToFile()` method should be virtual.
How can I deal with it?

Comment: Put them back to be separate functions... templates can not be `virtual`.

Comment: @TonyD, Isn't there a trick to do it?

Comment: @yaelaviv I've tried to do this. No, there isn't, unless you don't mind breaking the ability to have runtime polymorphism. Then you can (**kind of**) achieve this with [CRTP](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/17/the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-c/)

Comment: @yaelaviv: that depends what "it" is... if your use of templates is just meant to avoid duplicate code in the base class implementations, then you can have the non-templated member functions call a private non-virtual template member function that does the actual work, including calling virtual functions with known types if helpful.  If you want to have a class magically allow new client code to call it for new types, and have extra `virtual` functions spring into being - no.  Part of the idea with virtual functions is that virtual dispatch table is of known size and layout.

Comment: @TonyD, Thanks, What do you mean in "private non-virtual template member function"?

Comment: @yaelaviv: a member function with either the preceding access specified being `private:` or no access prior specifier in a `class`, that is not marked `virtual`, and is a `template`.  See Yochai's example, and note that the `template` can be made `private` while the `virtual` functions remain `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a virtual templated method (yet).
But, if you want the template just so you don't have to have the code everywhere , you can just call the templated method from within the overloaded methods **[(Code reuse)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse)**:

```
template < class T>
void WriteToFileT(T content)
{
    streamFile << content;
    streamFile << flush;
}  

virtual void WriteToFile( double content) //for double
{
   WriteToFileT(content);
}

virtual void WriteToFile( int content) //for integer
{
   WriteToFileT(content);
}
```

There are a lot of discussions about this...

[Can a C++ class member function template be virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual)
[C++ Virtual template method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968023/c-virtual-template-method)
[How to achieve "virtual template function" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871722/how-to-achieve-virtual-template-function-in-c)

Comment: @TonyD I was imagining that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One trick to obtain a "templated virtual method" is to have a templated, non-virtual method in the base class, doing all the templatey stuff, then passing the results in a runtime-polymorphic form to a virtual helper function. For instance, here you could have a `template<typename T> void WriteToFile(T)` in the base class, which converted the argument to a string, then passed that string to a `virtual void WriteToFile_aux(string)` method.

Of course, this relies on being able to separate the parametric polymorphism from the subtype polymorphism.