# C++11: perfect forward through base class pointer to derived class method

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, perfect-forwarding, template-function

I am looking to perfectly forward a parameter pack through a base class pointer to a derived class that holds a method pointer of a particular type, and then call that method pointer with the perfectly forwarded parameter pack. The `Sender<cARGS>` class has the container `std::set<ReceiverBase<cARGS>*>`. I want to iterate the container with the same parameter pack values (this I know how to do). Different `ReceiverBase<cARGS>*` will have different derived class (`Receiver<cPARENT, cARGS>`) method pointer types, but the parameter pack types will be the same (the cPARENT type in the derived class is the method pointer type). I have this working as expected with parameter pack being copied. Now I wish to add perfect forwarding like so:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void Notify(Ts&&...args)
{
    (m_parent->*m_notifyMethod)(std::forward(args)...);
}
```

I understand that I cannot have a virtual template method. I tried to use employ a double dispatch visitor pattern, but I'm not sure how to do this when I cannot know the type of the class that hold the method pointer.

```
template <typename ...cARGS>
class RecevierBase
{
public:
    virtual void Notify(cARGS...) = 0;
};


template <typename cPARENT, typename ...cARGS>
class Recevier : public RecevierBase<cARGS...>
{
    typedef void (cPARENT::* NOTIFY_METHOD)(cARGS...);
public:
    Recevier(cPARENT *parent, NOTIFY_METHOD notifyMethod) :
        m_parent(parent), m_notifyMethod(notifyMethod)
    {  }

    virtual void Notify(cARGS... args)
    {
        (m_parent->*m_notifyMethod)(args...);
    }

private:
    cPARENT *m_parent;
    NOTIFY_METHOD m_notifyMethod;
};
```

Comment: seems like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871722/how-to-achieve-virtual-template-function-in-c/7629011) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, I did see that one, yes.

Comment: You are probably looking for `(m_parent->*m_notifyMethod)(std::forward<cARGS>(args)...);`.  [Demo](http://rextester.com/ICX40834)

Comment: @howardhinnant, care to take a look at my question?