# Flexible return type for std::function, when the std::function is an argument of a virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, std-function

My question is related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871722/how-to-achieve-virtual-template-function-in-c), but in the context of `std::function`.

I have a virtual function that needs to take a `std::function` as an argument. However, I want the user to be able to choose `std::function`'s return type in their application code.

As a concrete example, say we have a base class `ProbabilityDistribution`, with `NormalDistribution`, `CauchyDistribution`, `UniformDistribution` being its derived classes.

Suppose a virtual member function `compute_weighted_expectation` takes a `std::function` that provides a function to integrate against the given distribution. So if the `std::function` returns a scalar, we are integrating against a 1-d function. If `std::function` returns a vector, we are integrating against a set of n 1-d functions and so on.

```
class ProbabilityDistribution
{
public:
    ProbabilityDistribution() {}
    virtual ~ProbabilityDistribution() {}

private:

    template<typename weight_type=float>
    virtual weight_type compute_weighted_expectation(std::function<weight_type(weight_type)> weight_definition) = 0;
}
```

If the user wanted to integrate a function f(x) = x^2 against a Normal, they could do,

```
NormalDistribution normal_dist(mean, variance);
std::function<float(float)> square = [](float a) { return a*a; };
normal_dist.compute_weighted_expectation<float>(square);
```

If they wanted to integrate vector of functions [f1(x) f2(x) f3(x)] against a Cauchy,

```
CauchyDistribution cauchy_dist(location, scale);
std::function<std::vector<float>(std::vector<float>)> vector_square = [](std:vector<float> a) { return std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), a.begin(), std::multiplies<float>()); };
cauchy_dist.weighted_expectation<std::vector<float>>(vector_square);
```

Now this wont compile, because templates are not allowed around virtual functions. Is there a way I can achieve this functionality without using templates ?

**[EDIT]**

The actual polymorphic class I am dealing with is in the context of a strategy pattern. The integration against probability distributions is the closest analog I could think ok.

So say that there is a `RandomVariable` class that takes a generic `ProbabilityDistribution` object in its constructor. The user selects the specific type of `ProbabilityDistribution` when they create a `RandomVariable` object.

```
class RandomVariable
{
public:

RandomVariable(std::unique_ptr<ProbabilityDistribution> _distribution):rv_distribution(_distribution) {};

~RandomVariable() {};

private:
std::unique_ptr<ProbabilityDistribution> rv_distribution;

float get_expectation() {return rv_distribution->compute_weighted_expectation(std::function<float(float)> _identity); };
}
```

User invocation:

```
NormalDistribution normal_dist(mean, variance);
RandomVariable rv_1(normal_dist);
rv_1.get_expectation();
```

Comment: do you really need the function to be virtual ? In the code you posted no polymorphism is used and `compute_weighted_mean` could be a normal member of `NormalDistribution` and `CauchyDistribution`.

Comment: Thank you @jarod42 for the edits and corrections to the code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I have clarified the context for the question. The base class ProbabiltyDistributions needs to be abstract to implement a strategy pattern.

Answer (score 3):

A virtual function means, "I can call the base version without knowing the concrete class, and the right thing will happen."

Your scenario says, "I need to know the concrete distribution so that I can supply the correct type of weight."

These two statements are incompatible. You will have to rethink your approach to the issue. Do you really need these distributions to have a common base? If you do, then you need to come up with a different way of supplying the weight.

Comment: I have expanded the question to include the strategy pattern context in which ProbabilityDistributions needs to be abstract.